# Select all data from table by comparing mutually exclusive values in the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access table as show below, Where **Item 1** and **Item 2** are mutually exclusive.
[image]

I need a query to generate the following result
[image]

1. Always retrieves all the entries of the table
2. If both **Item 1** and **Item 2** is present (manual editing of database is possible) only values of **Item 2** will be returned in the result.
3. Original table should not be altered

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IIF(Condition, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)` statement:

```
SELECT Id, IIF([Item 1] IS NOT NULL AND [Item 2] IS NOT NULL, NULL, [Item 1]) AS [Item 1], [Item 2]

FROM TableName
```

[Office Support IIF Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3?CorrelationId=222c9461-2836-4f96-9946-58703cb3355e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I believe the above one will return all the entries of the table as it is. Will it change the **item 1** to null if **item 2** exists.

Comment: @Saneeshkumar, IIF() will return exactly what you want. If Item1 and Item2 are not null (as in condition part, the first argument of IIF) the returned value is NULL, otherwise it returns Item1 value

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, its better to use the case statement along with the ranking functions..